# How to monitor or print transfer state and speed for different percentage of SFTP file transfer with WinSCP?

Tags: sftp, winscp

I am running automating the process of SFTP, so I am running the commands

```
open sftp://username:passwordd@192.xxx.xxx.x/ 

# Change LOCAL directory
lcd "C:\Users\Desktop\" 

# copy an individual file 
put -nopermissions -preservetime "C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.webm" xyz.webm
```

and getting an output

```
C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.webm | 60734 KB | 3160.3 KB/s | binary | 100%
```

So while transferring this I want the output the same output for different percentages. Like would want to know the size, throughput for 20%, 40%, 60% and so on...

Here we are getting a consolidated output but would want output in steps.

Is there a way to do it or a command to get output in steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), instead of a plain scripting.

The assembly has [`Session.FileTransferProgress` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress).

Handle the event to monitor the `FileTransferProgressEventArgs.FileProgress` – when it exceeds one of your thresholds, read the state from the `FileTransferProgressEventArgs.FileName`, `.FileProgress` and `.CPS`.

See [`FileTransferProgressEventArgs` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_filetransferprogresseventargs).